# Handling a dynamic amount of checkboxes with PHP

Tags: php, checkbox

I'm making a form that requires me to use a varying amount of checkboxes. Anywhere from 0 to n. I can easily insert the value I want into the value="" of the checkbox, so that's not a problem.

My question is - how would I write a PHP form that can take any amount of checkbox values from 1 to n, and then loop through all of those values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do this for your HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="your_supplied_value1"  />
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="your_supplied_value2"  />

if (isset($_POST['checkbox'])) {
  foreach ($_POST['checkbox'] as $c) {
    // do something 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use the array type for the name

name="name[]"

This passes an array to $_POST['name']  which you can foreach through

Answer (score -1):

Something like this:

```
<?php
for($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
    ?><input type="checkbox" name="checkthisbox[<?=$i?>]" value="value" /> checkbox :)<?php
}
?>
```

then loop through them like this:

```
<?php
foreach ($_POST['checkthisbox'] as $checkbox) {
    var_dump($checkbox);
}
?>
```

untested, but something like this should work